# A word denoting the sound of turning pages

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, sounds

The two words (adjectives) I found in [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120308120704AAXcw36) site, that perhaps (I am not sure) describe the sound of turning pages, when they rifled by the wind: fluttering and flapping.

Other than those adjectives mentioned above, is there any noun or noun phrase that refer to the sound of turning pages when being rifled by a wind. The word that I need doesn't necessarily have to do with the sound produced when we manually (by hands) turn the page(s) of books.

> I heard the ______ of
>   the turning pages, as
>   they were rifled by the
>   wind.
>
> [image: picture of turning pages]

Comment: Flap, flutter (as you suggested), slap, whipping, whirring... or you might just refer to hearing the wind rifling the pages - most readers would understand that as a sound on its own.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, it's been edited by **James**. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a **[flutter](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/flutter)**. It looks like a verb, but it's also a noun.

> Flutter means to move back and forth rapidly. Flags flutter in the wind. Leaves flutter to the ground. Flutter also exists as a noun—you might feel a flutter in your heart when you're excited.

So your example sentence should be:

- I heard the **flutter** of
  the turning pages, as
  they were rifled by the
  wind.

---

Someone can regard it as a **[paper flutter](https://freesound.org/people/mickdow/sounds/320913/)** as well.

Comment: Flutter isn't a sound, it's a movement.

Comment: You can still hear such a movement.  Good answer flutter is.

Comment: @user22542 - Yes, and I can hear the sound of a car skidding, but "skidding" is not "a word *denoting the sound*" which is what the OP asked for. "Squeal" or "screech" would be appropriate instead.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for the verb **[to rustle](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rustling?s=t)**:

> to make a succession of slight, soft sounds, as of parts rubbing gently one on another, as leaves, silks, or papers.

<sup>dictionary.com</sup>

In particular I'd use the -ing form:

> I heard the **rustling** of the turning pages, as they were rifled by the wind.

Comment: But I did **not** downvote this.

Comment: Is rustling a noun here?

Comment: Rustling sounds perfect, wether it's a gerund or noun.

Comment: Rustle is also a noun, as mentioned by Oxford and Cambridge Dictionaries.

Comment: @JamesWolpert - It's definitely a gerund and/or a noun... (I've never been too hot on whether a gerund *is* a noun or whether it's just *acting* as one. If you scroll down the dictionary.com link, in the British dictionary section it does state that "rustling" can be a noun, but I don't know whether it is in this case or not.)

Answer (score 0):

I looked for an adjective for the sound of flipping pages as in when you thumb through a book to find the right page and couldn't find one that fit so I made up my own sound, "fripping." I'm going with that.